# Get source code from App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Is it possible to download copies of our application's code from the Google App Engine servers?

Using `appcfg.py` we upload the files. Wondering if there's something similar we can use to download the source code from App Engine?

For e.g. If we loose the source code locally, is it possible to get it from Google App Engine server where the python application is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can.. if it was not disabled by the admin

are you using python, java or go ?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp?hl=en#Downloading_Source_Code

also see `./appcfg.sh help download_app`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. Create a new directory for storing the downloaded files. The App Engine runtime requires that the directory be empty before it can download the files to that directory.
2. Switch to the directory where App Engine is installed on your computer. It is usually under the following path: `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine`
3. Execute the following command to download the project. Remember to replace MyAppName with the ID of your own App Engine project.
   `appcfg.py download_app - A MyAppName -V 1 c:\AppEngine\SourceCode`

It'll ask for your Google Account credentials and once authenticated, all the source code files will instantly download to the specified directory.

(from: http://www.labnol.org/software/download-appengine-files/19348/)

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Updated with contents instead of just a link.